# Using Sharpdevelop Addin Architecture to develop WPF application

Tags: wpf, add-in, sharpdevelop

I am new to this AddIns architecture but it really seems fascinating to me. I downloaded shardevelop code to understand it but it is too huge and the examples given are using Winforms. I want to use WPF. Can you please provide me some links where they have used sharpdevelop with WPF?

Regards,
Priyank Thakkar

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, SharpDevelop code base is your best resource.

BTW, did you check out MEF from Microsoft?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx